# Removing current Python version and using another Python version

Tags: macos, terminal, macports, python

First of all I installed python 2.7 with manual. After I installed Python 2.6 with Macports with referenced [this](http://www.phacks.net/python-pyqt-twisted-on-osx-snowleopard/).

And after that I deleted my Python 2.7 files.

The main point is when I type `python` at terminal get this:

```
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

But if I type the command `python2.6` the Python works with all components (like PyQt).

So how can I activate `python` command?

Comment: Depending on which version of OS X you are running, you may have deleted the system-installed version of python (which looks likely based on the path). Have you considered downloading the latest combo update and re-installing the base system to see if that remedies your issue? http://support.apple.com/downloads/#combo

Comment: I remove my python version as referenced (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/1149102) this answer. Is it necessary re-installing base system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably have two options, barring a reinstallation of 2.7, which might be the easiest thing to do.

You can include the following first line in every Python script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.6
```

Change the path to reflect the version and location of the Python you would like to use.

Alternately you could create a bash alias like:

```
alias python = '/path/to/pythonversion'
```

I would go with the first version myself.

Comment: There is no bin directory at /usr/local/ , i guess deleted.  But when i write `python2.6 example.py` execute correctly.I may try second option but can you show me what  is my python version path. (I remind that i installed python2.6 with macport.)

Comment: Thanks everyove. Solved - http://superuser.com/a/225118/209046